# How to automatically update a webpage to show new entries in mysql database table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am actually building a chatbox and for this, I used js to continuously load the chatlog after fixed interval of time. I am able to see the new entries but the problem is that I am not able to scroll up the page to see older chats as the chatlog keeps on reloading after the given time interval.

Link to the project: https://github.com/PsYcO-kk/ChatBox

Comment: there are a few dozen similar projects you could just look at and follow the process

Answer (score 0):

You need a JS variable, which store how many messages has been loaded. 
You need a PHP file, which gets the ajax requests, and waiting a "from", and "count" parameter.
from: define the starting point of messages
count: define how many messages need to load.
The PHP file should works backwards. So from 20, count 10, means return 10 messages: 10. 11. 12. 13. etc...

I think you should check the box scroll status, and if when the status is on top, you should send an ajax request.
The ajax request has 2 parameter: from, and count.

I think you should work with json format in ajax.